# Не работает событие click() - jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте. Написал скрипт с использованием AJAX. Суть скрипта заключается в том, чтобы выводить входящие сообщения из БД. Скрипт выполняется каждую секунду дабы не пропустить сообщение.

```
$('.accept-btn').click(function() { 
    var id_session = $(this).closest('div p.msg-t').prev().text();
    acceptMessage(id_session);
    generateChat(id_session);
    e.preventDefault();         
})

function generateChat(id_session) {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'generatechat.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'id_session': id_session},
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function () {
        $('.all-chats').html("Не удалось создать чат.");
    }
    });
}

function acceptMessage(id_session) {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'accept.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'id_session': id_session},
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function () {

    }
  });
}
```

Скрипт который выполняется каждую секунду, запускающий обращение к БД и вытаскивающий оттуда сообщения.

```
var interval = 1000;
show();
setInterval('show()', interval);

function show() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'show.php',
    timeout: 10000, 
    success: function(data) {;
      $('.msg-to-all').html(data);
    },
    error: function() {
      $('.msg-to-all').html("Не удалось загрузить сообщения");
    }
  });
}
```

Вопрос: Почему не удается нажимать на кнопку? Из за обновления блока с новыми сообщениями событие click() становится недоступным. Как это исправить? Заранее спасибо..)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте метод `jQuey` `on()`. Таки образом:

```
$('.accept-btn').on('click', function() { 
    var id_session = $(this).closest('div p.msg-t').prev().text();
    acceptMessage(id_session);
    generateChat(id_session);
    e.preventDefault();         
});
```

Comment: Дело в том, что когда я вставляю блок который должен генерироваться динамически из БД, статически, т.е просто вставляю его в HTML все отлично работает.

Comment: а чем это отличается от `$('.accept-btn').click` ?

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать так

```
$('body').on('click','.accept-btn', function() {
    var id_session = $(this).closest('div p.msg-t').prev().text();
    acceptMessage(id_session);
    generateChat(id_session);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**UPD:** А на чем стоит `preventDefault`? В Вашем коде обработчику клика не передается переменная e.

Comment: Я вернулся к старому .click() там у меня в функции передается e. Данные берутся из БД через php, надеюсь вы понимаете о чем я?